# Angular 2 setting Control values after ajax response

Tags: angular

Hi i am trying to create a form with soem validation an I seem to have come into some issues when I create a select box and try to asign it a value after an ajax call.

Here si the code that builds the form:

```
  export class StoreRegistrationComponent implements OnInit  {
    public countries: Array<StoreViewModel.CountryViewModel>;
    public hasFormBeenSubmitted: boolean;               
    public storeRegistrationForm: ControlGroup;

    public ngOnInit() {
            this.storeDataService.getCountries().subscribe(countries => {
                this.countries = countries
                this.storeRegistrationForm.value.userCountryId = this.countries[0].id;
                this.storeRegistrationForm.value.storeCountryId = this.countries[0].id;
            });
            this.buildStoreRegistrationForm();     
    }  

    private buildStoreRegistrationForm() {
        this.storeRegistrationForm = this.formBuilder.group({
           userCountryId: new Control('', Validators.compose([])),
           storeCountryId: new Control('', Validators.compose([])),
       }); 
    }
```

}

```
      <form novalidate (ngSubmit)="registerStore()" [ngFormModel]="storeRegistrationForm">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>{{text.label.country}}</label>
                    <select class="form-control" ngControl="userCountryId">
                        <option *ngFor="#country of countries" [value]="country.id">{{country.name}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>{{text.label.storeCountry}}</label>
                    <select class="form-control" ngControl="storeCountryId">
                        <option *ngFor="#country of countries" [value]="country.id">{{country.name}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-right">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <span>{{text.label.finish}}</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Now what I want to achieve here is when the request from the server arrives with the countrues to set the default value for the select box based on the first element in the array.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: But why don't you use `[(ngModel)]` instead?

Comment: This makes it easier to write tests for the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either move the call to `this.buildStoreRegistrationForm();` into the `subscribe()` callback to delay the for creation until the `countries` values arrived:

```ts
public ngOnInit() {
  this.storeDataService.getCountries().subscribe(countries => {
    this.countries = countries
    this.storeRegistrationForm.value.userCountryId = this.countries[0].id;
    this.storeRegistrationForm.value.storeCountryId = this.countries[0].id;
    this.buildStoreRegistrationForm();     
  });
}
```

or you can update the values using

```ts
public ngOnInit() {
  this.storeDataService.getCountries().subscribe(countries => {
    this.countries = countries;
    this.storeRegistrationForm.controls['userCountryId'].updateValue( this.countries[0].id);
    this.storeRegistrationForm.controls['storeCountryId'].updateValue( this.countries[0].id);
  });
}
```